# Authorization Bearer Token Header in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, proxy, authorization, bearer-token

I am trying to create a header for an authorization bearer token that I generated from the API's side. I am using CORS-anywhere to call the API and get the data through JSON. I was wondering, what is the correct format for the authorization bearer token header?

Answer (score 6):

Without any more information to go off of, typically an `Authorization` header that uses a bearer token should look like the following:

`Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM`

In javascript, typically it involves setting the `Authorization` property of a headers object:

```
// headers you pass to a http request
let headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
};
```

Usually a http request library will taken in a parameter for headers somewhere that you would pass this to.

Is there something more specific you want to know?

Comment: Does the token need to be in parenthesis or anything like that? My token involves a ~, prompting my code to have an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '~'. My example: 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' xxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Yup it needs to be in quotes: 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + 'xxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: In my case, bearer should be typed "Bearer". It's case sensible.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) has the following syntax:

`Authorization: <type> <credentials>`

For your particular use case i.e. using a Bearer Token the request header should be:

`Authorization: Bearer <token>`