# How to assign bearer token to authorization header in javaScript

Tags: javascript, api, bearer-token

I'm trying to make a GET request from the instructure-canvas API that requires a bearer token. I'm able to do so via both Postman and a curl command they provided me with:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS-TOKEN>" "https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses"
```

Both these methods work and I am returned with the proper json data. However, I was wondering if there exists a way of doing this same operation in JavaScript (with or without additional libraries/frameworks). Apologies if this is trivial, I am very new to working with API's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization Bearer Token Header in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164935/authorization-bearer-token-header-in-javascript)

Comment: There are a whole ton of questions like this.  Search for `[javascript] bearer token`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're making the request from the browser, you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It'll look a little something like this:

```js
const url = ""; // API URL
const token = ""; // API Token
const method = "GET"; // Request method, change for what's needed

fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` // This is the important part, the auth header
    }
}).then(res => res.json().then(console.log)).catch(console.error); // Do better handling here
```

Depending on the server setup, you may need additional headers. Also keep an eye on the console for errors relating to CORs, as once again they will differer depending on how the server has been configured.